# Find if string contains value and then extract

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone, streamreader

Hello i'm trying to to create a little webapp for windows phone.
It pulls down a wepage and saves the source code in a textblock, what i want to do is have the app read that text block and determine if in contains a set value = "http://test.com" if it does I want it to extract the full url.

so far what i have is

```
        string stringToCheck = "http://test.com";
        string stringhtml = invisiBlockHtml.Text;

        if (stringhtml.Contains(stringToCheck))
        {
            // StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stringhtml);
            // here i was hoping there was some way for StreamReader or another function to read the string and then pull out the full url



        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("found Url", UriKind.Absolute));  }

        else
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://dontcontain.com", UriKind.Absolute));
        }`
```

Hope this makes sense, I have only very recently started programming.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match

Comment: You cannot do that. I guess stringHtml can be any text containing url appear anywhere. So even regular expression cannot help in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will try to get a url match

```
string mystring = "My text and url http://www.google.com and some more text.";

Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"(?<url>(http:[/][/]|www.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[/.]|[~])*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

MatchCollection matches = urlRx.Matches(mystring);
```

Comment: thanks mate, im just trying to put it in.. would it work if i put Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"(?<url>(http:[/][/]|www.play)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[/.]|[~])*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); because there are multible url in the sring and i only want the one that starts with play?

Comment: MOdify url to Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"(?<url>(http:[/][/]|www.http://test.com)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[/.]|[~])*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Answer (score 0):

I commented, but here's a whole Regular Expression guide ->

[Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) for C#

[Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) A good place to test your regex

[Regex Matching](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match) How to get the matched value back from Regex in C# (your question)

**EDIT**

Though maybe i misunderstood the question.  Are you looking for an exact url, or any URL?  If you are looking for an exact URl, then if .Contains() returns true, you already know the url

Comment: Thanks I'm looking for a url that also has a long qurystring so i know the first part of the url but want to find the qurystring. Sorry about not explaining that.. and i'll take a look at regex thank you.. :-)